# Problem with ESLint, React/TS when trying to use export * syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

Is it possible to use `export * from './X'` with absolute import paths and eslint in react/typescript? I wanted to have single index.ts file in components folder that would export everything else but eslint gives me weird error when i'm trying to do this.

My current structure looks like this:

*src/components/Example1/Example1.tsx*

```
import React from 'react';

export type Props = {};
export const Example1 = (props: Props) => <div></div>
```

*src/components/Example1/index.ts*

```
export * from './Example1';
```

*src/components/index.ts*

```
export * from './Example1';
```

Both `index` files gives me error:
`0:0  error  Parsing error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Also when i try to import anything from the `components/index` file using an absolute path `import { Example1 } from 'components';` i have an error:

```
1:43  error  Parse errors in imported module 'components': Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (undefined:undefined)  import/namespace
1:43  error  Parse errors in imported module 'components': Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (undefined:undefined)  import/named
```

This is my `.eslintrc.json` file

```
  {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "jsx-a11y",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "import/newline-after-import": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "warn",
      { "args": "after-used", "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

My current `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.21.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.32",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "i18next": "^19.3.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^4.0.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.3.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2",
    "yup": "^0.28.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.23.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging yarn build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint . --ext .js,.tsx,.ts --max-warnings=0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .js,.tsx,.ts --fix",
    "watch": "react-scripts start",
    "deploy": "yarn build && firebase deploy",
    "deploy:staging": "yarn build:staging && firebase use staging && firebase deploy"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm also using lerna with yarn workspaces to easily handle MERN app.

Deleting eslint package / configs, node_modules did not help me, i still have `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error. It is super weird because in clean CRA everything works. I spent last 4 hours trying to solve this problem and finally used a workaround with importing types to root index file and reexporing them as new type but it's definately a painful solution. I need to keep isolatedModules. Maybe someone had similar problem?

Comment: Did you try with `as` keyword like `export * as Example from './Example1'`

Comment: Yep, it gives me: "Parsing error: 'from' expected. eslint", super weird

Comment: Does this related to your question? https://eslint.org/docs/7.0.0/rules/no-restricted-exports#known-limitations

Comment: I',m not using default exports so i guess there's no way this rule could help

Comment: Just started happening to me today too. Only change was some package updates.. i smell something broken in some core toolchain piece.

Comment: @Dooomel what versions of CRA and Typescript do you have? Maybe you can post your `package.json`

Comment: @DavidG sure, i edited my question with package.json file. As you see i',m using react-scripts 3.4.0 and typescript ~3.7.2

Comment: huh, interestingly we're both using GraphQL/apollo. So the way i fixed it  was by changing my import style. I don't have a better work around other than 
```import { Blah } from './blah'
export {
  Blah
}````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was @typescript-eslint package, check out the issue for more info:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1746

Fast fix for this is to downgrade packages to version 2.22.0:

`@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`

`@typescript-eslint/parser`

@Edit This helped with lint error but my CRA build is still crashing, I guess i will have to wait for package fix